# Jenkins Maven Project working on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to build a jenkins maven project job.It takes the code from bit bucket repo and executes "**clean install dependency:copy-dependencies**". It should generate a directory called "data" inside my target folder and copy the contents from the path given in pom.xml(see below) to the data folder. This execution when run on windows system it is generating this data folder inside my target. But when I execute the **SAME** on a linux machine, it is generating the target but no data folder inside it. Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Part of xml code looks like this:

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/data</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src\main\resources\org\optaplanner\examples</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **${file.separator}** instead of **\** in **directory**.
But **/** should work on windows.

replace

```
 <directory>src\main\resources\org\optaplanner\examples</directory>
```

by

```
 <directory>src${file.separator}main${file.separator}resources${file.separator}org${file.separator}optaplanner${file.separator}examples</directory>
```

or

```
<directory>src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples</directory>
```